# Polymorphism java error

Tags: java, polymorphism

This is the model class:

```
public class Test4
{
    public static void main(String []args)
 {
        Rectangle2 one = new Rectangle2(5, 20);
        Box2 two = new Box2(4, 10, 5);

      showEffectBoth(one);
      showEffectBoth(two);
  }

 public static void showEffectBoth(Rectangle2 r)
 {
     System.out.println(r);
 }
}
```

I am trying to create a `class` very similar to it, but it does not work. What am I supposed to change? I have created all those classes already.

```
public class testNew
{
 public void showEffectBoth(Rectangle3 r)
 {
  System.out.println(r);
 }

public static void main (String []args)
{
Rectangle3 one = new Rectangle3(5,20);
Box3 two = new Box3(4,4,4);
Box3 three = new Box3(4,10,5);
Cube3 four = new Cube3(4,4,4);

showEffectBoth(one);
showEffectBoth(two);
showEffectBoth(three);
showEffectBoth(four);
 }
}
```

When I try to compile it it says: `illegal start of expression`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> you are trying to use one common method which it's parameter is
>   accepting instances of various classes, in this case one good thing to
>   do is having an interface for all the classes to implement. you can use generics also.

```
public interface CommonInterface
{
  public void doSomeThing();
}
```

now implement it for other classes:

```
public class Box implements CommonInterface
{   
 @Override
 public void doSomeThing(){
  //do some thing;
 }

 //other fields or methods

 }
}
public class Rectangle implements CommonInterface
{   
 @Override
 public void doSomeThing(){
  //do some thing;
 }

 //other fields or methods

 }
}
```

now you can have the common method like:

```
 public void showEffectBoth(CommonInterface r)
 {
     r.doSomeThing();
 }
```

and you can call it like this:

```
Rectangle one = new Rectangle(5, 20);
Box two = new Box(4, 10, 5);

showEffectBoth(one);
showEffectBoth(two);
```

**Note:** your interface can have nothing inside, in this case also you can have for example:

```
 public void showEffectBoth(CommonInterface r)
 {
     System.out.println(r);
 }
```

and

```
  Rectangle one = new Rectangle(5, 20);
  Box two = new Box(4, 10, 5);

  showEffectBoth(one);
  showEffectBoth(two);
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got a method inside of another method -- something that you can't do in Java.

```
public class testNew {
   public static void main (String []args) {
      Rectangle3 one = new Rectangle3(5,20);
      Box3 two = new Box3(4,4,4);
      Box3 three = new Box3(4,10,5);
      Cube3 four = new Cube3(4,4,4);

      showEffectBoth(one);
      showEffectBoth(two);
      showEffectBoth(three);
      showEffectBoth(four);

      // you can't nest this method here
      public void showEffectBoth(Rectangle3 one) {
         System.out.println(one);
      }
   }
}
```

Your code indentation is imprecise, and this is preventing you from seeing your error. Conversely, if you work to indent your code well, the problem would have become immediately obvious to you, and this is one reason why it is so important to learning and use proper indentation. It is paramount towards creating good code.

Solution: separate your methods.

Other "side" recommendations, you will want to learn and use [Java naming conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming)#Java). Variable names should all begin with a lower letter while class names with an upper case letter. Following these suggestions as well as following good code formatting practices will allow others (such as us!) to better understand your code, and more importantly, will allow your future self to better understand just what you were thinking 6 months ago when you wrote the code.

Also, note the location of the error message as it will likely occur right above the offending nested method. In the future if you look carefully at the location of compiler errors (and JVM exceptions), you will often find the offending code and be able to fix it.